# Can one copy a directory to the attachment directory through the org-attach dialog?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When I try to copy a directory with C-c C-a c I get an error message simply stating "File is a directory". Is there a way to use the convenience of the attachment library with folders ?

Comment: I don't think so. You can use `org-attach-dired-to-subtree` to attach multiple files from a `dired` buffer to a subtree, but AFAIK, they got to be regular files - probably because one of the attachment methods (the hardlink method) cannot be used on directories and it would be a mess to always check if the underlying method supported the required operation - but that is just guessing on my part.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I will look into org-attach-direct[...] even tho doesn't seem to be what I need.